# How to solve size mismatch error in Python (Pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-regression

I am currently working on multivariate linear regression using PyTorch and I am getting the following error, I did search a lot about this error and the only thing I got to know is that there is a size mismatch between data and labels. But how to solve this error. Please help me or show me the right way to solve this problem.

**size mismatch, m1: [824 x 1], m2: [8 x 8]**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np


Xtr = np.loadtxt("TrainData.csv")
Ytr = np.loadtxt("TrainLabels.csv")


X_train = torch.FloatTensor(Xtr)
Y_train = torch.FloatTensor(Ytr)

#### MODEL ARCHITECTURE #### 

class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(8,8)
        self.lin2 = torch.nn.Linear(8,1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.lin2(x)
        y_pred = self.linear(x)
        return y_pred

model = Model()

loss_func = nn.MSELoss(size_average=False)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
#print(len(list(model.parameters())))
def count_params(model): 
    return sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)

### TRAINING 
for epoch in range(2):
    y_pred = model(X_train)

    loss = loss_func(y_pred, Y_train)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    count = count_params(model)
    print(count)

test_exp = torch.FloatTensor([[6.0]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the order of operations in your forward pass is incorrect. The short answer is swap them as shown below. More context on the various shapes below.

```
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.lin2(x)
        y_pred = self.linear(x)
        return y_pred
```

Should be:

```
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear(x)
        y_pred = self.lin2(x)
        return y_pred
```

Assuming that you have 8 features and some batch size `N` your input data to the forward pass will have size `(N x 8)`. After you pass it through `lin2` it will have shape `(N x 1)`.  The `linear` node expects an input with shape `(N x 8)` but it's getting `(N x 1)` hence the error.